# How can I align texts to the left in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a really simple app here, which just has some texts on it.
The problem here is, React adds some white spaces at the beginning of the new line automatically.
I applied "textAlign: "left", but no luck.
I'm not really sure, but I think this behavier happens when I　insert a line break in the object of an array. (But actually, some words are put on the new line by themselves with the spaces...)

[image: This is the screen]

Here is my app:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

function App(props) {
  const test = [
    {
      text: `Once upon a time, in a small village nestled at the foot of a
      magnificent mountain range, there lived a young girl named Ava.

      Ava was known for her adventurous spirit and her insatiable curiosity about the world beyond her village. 

      She had listened to countless stories of
      far-off lands and magical creatures, filling her heart with dreams of
      exploration. 
      
      One sunny morning, as Ava ventured into the woods near her
      village, she stumbled upon an ancient-looking map hidden beneath a
      moss-covered rock.
      
      The map depicted a mysterious island far across the
      ocean, said to hold the key to a hidden treasure.
      
      Excitement coursed through Ava's veins as she made up her mind to embark on an unforgettable journey.
      
      With the map tightly clutched in her hands, Ava hurriedly packed her backpack with essential supplies and set off towards the coast. She managed to convince a wise old sailor named Captain Benjamin to lend her his boat, the Silver Wave, and together they set sail towards the fabled island.`,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{test[0].text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    color: "black",
    textAlign: "left",
  },
});
export default App;
```

How can I ask React not to add the spaces and align texts to the left?
Thank you in advance.

==========Edit=================
After playing aroud with it, I managed to align them to the left.
In my editor VScode, I removed the spaces that were inserted automatically probably because of the extention "Prettier"

Now the file is like this, it's bacome quite ugry:
[image: Here is what my file looks like.]

But, whenever I want to align them to the left, would I have to remove the spaces manually? That would be a pain and I don't believe that what people do for that...

Does anyone know how to tackle on this in a more common way?

==========Edit2==================

I found a way to remove the spaces by making use of the 'replace' method.
Here is the appdated code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

function App(props) {
  const test = [
    {
      text: `Once upon a time, in a small village nestled at the foot of a
      magnificent mountain range, there lived a young girl named Ava.

      Ava was known for her adventurous spirit and her insatiable curiosity about the world beyond her village. 

      She had listened to countless stories of
      far-off lands and magical creatures, filling her heart with dreams of
      exploration. 
      
      One sunny morning, as Ava ventured into the woods near her
      village, she stumbled upon an ancient-looking map hidden beneath a
      moss-covered rock.
      
      The map depicted a mysterious island far across the
      ocean, said to hold the key to a hidden treasure.
      
      Excitement coursed through Ava's veins as she made up her mind to embark on an unforgettable journey.
      
      With the map tightly clutched in her hands, Ava hurriedly packed her backpack with essential supplies and set off towards the coast. She managed to convince a wise old sailor named Captain Benjamin to lend her his boat, the Silver Wave, and together they set sail towards the fabled island.`,
    },
  ];

  //Remove spaces
  const trimmedText = test[0].text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{trimmedText}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    color: "black",
    textAlign: "left",
  },
});
export default App;
```

But this time, I've lost the line breaks...

Comment: Add white-space property on text

Comment: I tried white-space: normal; that fixed on web. But for mobile it is not fixing. And by manually removing the space that caused due to prettier, it also work for mobile. And yeah its a pain by manually removing. But white-space property not working on mobile.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time testting that! I actually have 1000 files that have texts like this. Thinking about fixing each of them by hand is killing me.

Comment: i tried almost many properties but not fixing on mobile.

Comment: Yeah I tried too, but I couldn't find one...but I acutually found another way to remove the space using "replace" method. I edited and added the code. But this time, I lost the line breaks...it seems like things don't go the way I like

Comment: Yes, using js it is possible as you trim the text. I was trying to find a way on css. But its not workiing.

Comment: Yes line-breaks will go

Comment: Due you want to keep the line breaks? Right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to deal with this using a property if it's possible, because it's easier and simpler! But no luck.

Comment: Yes, I need line breakes

Comment: Ok, let me do this

Comment: Ok. I added an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
const trimmedText = test[0].text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/[.]/g, ".\n").replace(/\n\s/g, "\n\n");
```

1. The regex in first replace(/\s+/g, " ") will replace **All Spaces (including linefeed (\n))** with **single space**.
2. The regex in second replace(/[.]/g, ".\n") will replace **Full Stop** with **Full Stop and linefeed (\n)**.

Now after this second replace, everything is good except that each line has a single space in the start and there is no gap between lines. So, to add a line break and remove starting space in each line, I used third replace with regex:-

3. The regex in third replace(/\n\s/g, "\n\n") will replace where **linefeed and space** together present with **double linefeed (\n)**. One linefeed is just for repeating the previous line feed and the second linefeed is doing two purposes at a same time. It will remove the starting space and also put the linefeed which will show the spacing.

You can remove all replace() and then add replace one by one to better understand what is happening.

Hope the explanation will be helpful.

Comment: Wow this works like a charm! This way, I wounldn't need to do it manually, you're a life saver! By the way, what does this exactly do if you don't mind me asking? `replace(/\n\s/g, "\n\n")`

Comment: Without that part, the form of the sentenses break. So with the part `/\n\s/g,`, you first find a line break and a white spase, and then you replase them with two line breaks, correct? Because Prettier somehow put a white space after a line break??

Comment: @sahasrabhujaneuron I will update the answer with explanation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! Now I understand how it works! I really appreciate your help and I'm not in a positon to say this, but it was enjoyable playing around with this problem with you. Thank you so much for your kindness man!

Comment: @sahasrabhujaneuron I also enjoyed it. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write your text file in a single line and add \n to indicate that its a new line it will work fine, look at the formatting below

eg:

```
const test = [
    {
      text: `Once upon a time, in a small village nestled at the foot of a magnificent mountain range, there lived a young girl named Ava.
      \nAva was known for her adventurous spirit and her insatiable curiosity about the world beyond her village. 
      \nShe had listened to countless stories of far-off lands and magical creatures, filling her heart with dreams of exploration. 
      \nOne sunny morning, as Ava ventured into the woods near her village, she stumbled upon an ancient-looking map hidden beneath a moss-covered rock.
      \nThe map depicted a mysterious island far across the ocean, said to hold the key to a hidden treasure.
      \nExcitement coursed through Ava's veins as she made up her mind to embark on an unforgettable journey.
      \nWith the map tightly clutched in her hands, Ava hurriedly packed her backpack with essential supplies and set off towards the coast. She managed to convince a wise old sailor named Captain Benjamin to lend her his boat, the Silver Wave, and together they set sail towards the fabled island.`,
    },
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Basically he had 1000 files, he can't do this.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution! I would've gone with this if I hadn't had too many files...but thank you for your help!